# Email Alert when Crashes cross a particular Threshold

Tags: ios, email, crash, analytics, alert

Is it possible to setup an email alert when the number of crashes in my app crosses a particular threshold per day?

I would like to receive an email, for example, when my app crashes more than 7 times in the last 24 hs.

I'm tracking the crashes with **Crashlytics** (from **Fabric**). I didn't find anything related within Settings -> Notifications nor in any google research.

I sent an email to support@fabric.io, still waiting to their response.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

I resent my reply from our support channel as well.

There is not a custom notification that can be sent, but let me clarify what is currently available.

New Issue: A new issue email would be sent when an issue first appears in Fabric for the very first time.

Regressed Issue: If an issue has been closed and happens in a version outside the subset of versions where the issue had occurred previously, then you'll be notified.

Crash Stability Digest: A digest email contianing a summary of your issues including any issues that are new or trending higher and thus may be worth investigating as a priority.

Issue Velocity Alert: If an issue is causing a crash in 1% of all user sessions within the past hour, you'll be notifiied.

Stability Alert: If your app's stability drops below a statistically significant amount based on historical data, then you'll be notified.

Perhaps some combination of these could help?

Comment: Many thanks Mike, I appreciate your time and response.

You were very clear and for sure, it will help!