# When are issue velocity alerts sent

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I have configured Fabric and Crashlytics in my application. I have added the call to test crashes:

```
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

I am seeing those crashes reported in the Dashboard with the stack traces and everything.

In the Settings menu under *Notifications*, I have all the alerts set to **On**, including *Issue Velocity Alert*.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396175/email-alert-when-crashes-cross-a-particular-threshold/44413486#44413486) the Issue Velocity Alert:

> If an issue is causing a crash in 1% of all user sessions within the past hour, you'll be notifiied.

I have received a *New Fatal Issue Alert* for the calls to `crash()` which shows the I am receiving alerts correctly.

But I haven't received any Issue Velocity Alert. Since 100% of my sessions have crashed to the same error, I should be receiving it right? The first crash happened 3 hours ago.

Note that I have tested it with 1 user on 1 device.

Why am I not receiving any alerts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul from Fabric here. Crashlytics has a minimum threshold of unique users of an app before Velocity Alerts will be sent. I can't say what the exact numbers are, but they're designed to prevent apps with few users from getting spammed by our issue reporting.

Comment: Do you know if we could have an order of magnitude for the approximate number of users needed to see those alerts?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found out looking into it:

> - An issue in an app exceeds the defined threshold for that app.
> - The app has 250 sessions in that time period.
> - There was no alert previously raised for the issue in the app.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/velocity-alerts

Personally, I find the name **velocity alert** quite misleading.

Comment: Yes this is quite confusing, does this mean that 250 will trigger the alert, or that at least 250 are needed to trigger it?

I can find apps where 250 is too many, and other where 0.1% is too low. (when you have millions of users)